# Vectors Concatenation

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch

Suppose I have three vectors A, B, C

> ```
> A vector size of 256
> B vector size of 256
> C vector size of 256
> ```

Now I want to do concatenation in the following way:

> ```
> AB= vector size will be 512
> AC = vector size will be 512
> BC = vector size will be 512
> ```

**However,** I need to restrict all the concatenated vectors to *256*, like:

> ```
> AB= vector size will be 256
> AC = vector size will be 256
> BC = vector size will be 256
> ```

One way is to take the mean of each two values of the two vectors like `A first index value` and `B first index value`, `A second index value` and `B second index value` ... etc. Similarly, in the concatenation of other vectors.

**How I implement this:**

```
x # torch.Size([32, 3, 256]) # 32 is Batch size, 3 is vector A, vector B, vector C and 256 is each vector dimension

def my_fun(self, x):
        iter = x.shape[0]
        counter = 0
        new_x = torch.zeros((10, x.shape[1]), dtype=torch.float32, device=torch.device('cuda'))
        for i in range(0, x.shape[0] - 1):
            iter -= 1
            for j in range(0, iter):
                mean = (x[i, :] + x[i+j, :])/2
                new_x[counter, :] = torch.unsqueeze(mean, 0)
                counter += 1
        final_T = torch.cat((x, new_x), dim=0)
        return final_T

ref = torch.zeros((x.shape[0], 15, x.shape[2]), dtype=torch.float32, device=torch.device('cuda'))
for i in range (x.shape[0]):
    ref[i, :, :] = self.my_fun(x[i, :, :])
```

But this implementation is computationally expensive. One reason is I am iterating **batch-wise** which makes it computationally expensive. Is there any efficient way to implement this task?

Comment: Use the builtin `mean` instead of the `j` iteration.  `np.mean((A,B),axis=0)`.

Comment: But `A` and `B` are `torch` variables. So how I should use `numpy` here?

Comment: Getting error `TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.`

Answer (score 1):

Torch has a builtin mean method, which can calculate means element-wise.

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

allvectors=torch.stack((a,b,c), dim=0)
values=it.combinations([0,1,2], 2)

for i,j in values:
    pairedvectors=torch.stack((allvectors[i],allvectors[j]), dim=0)
    mean=torch.mean(pairedvectors,dim=0)
```

for 3 example vectors:

```
a=torch.from_numpy(np.zeros((5)))
b=torch.from_numpy(np.ones((5)))
c=torch.from_numpy(np.ones((5))*5)
```

It results in the following vectors:

```
tensor([0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000], dtype=torch.float64)
tensor([2.5000, 2.5000, 2.5000, 2.5000, 2.5000], dtype=torch.float64)
tensor([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Comment: Actually its computationally more expensive in my case. My posted code takes `44.81 seconds` per epoch in training while after updating code through `itertools`  each epoch takes `53.61s`.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the suggestion of using itertools. It just stays now as an easy way to show the example vectors.